# Highstock Flags Series with stacked data

Tags: highcharts

If you try to combine stacked series with a flag series there is an odd behaviour where only the flag series gets drawn. If you toggle it in the legend everything gets drawn properly.

http://jsfiddle.net/x9gaca75/

```
$("#container").highcharts({plotOptions: {series: {stacking: "normal"}}, ...});
```

What configuration am I missing to make this behave properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug in Highstock, where setting `plotOptions.series.stacking` will set the same for flags. Of course, stacking won't work for flags since those don't have values. In other words, workaround is to set `stacking = false` for flags:

```
    options.series.push({
        "stacking": false,  // disable stacking
        "show_in_legend": false,
        "name": "Flags",
        "type": "flags",
        "data": [{
            "x": 1432215000000.0,
            "title": "AM"
        }, {
            "x": 1432229400000.0,
            "title": "Midday"
        }, {
            "x": 1432245600000.0,
            "title": "Peak Hour"
        }, {
            "x": 1432247400000.0,
            "title": "Rolling, PM"
        }]
    });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/x9gaca75/1/